# Deb 6: Can't install Mongodb 64; uname -m and arch both return x86_64

Tags: 64-bit, mongodb, 32-bit

As the title suggests, in bash the commands `uname -m` and `arch` both return x86_64, suggesting to me that I'm on a 64bit OS and processor. But, when I use `aptitude` or `apt-get` to install the package mongodb-10gen, the 32-bit version is installed.

So, I tried downloading the 64bit tarball:

```
curl http://downloads.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.4.tgz > mongodb.tgz
tar -zxvf mongodb.tgz
```

But then, when I try to run one of the executables therein (from within the untarred directory) `./bin/mongo`, the response is "No such file or directory." The case is the same for all of the executables in the bin directory, though they very clearly DO exist.

What's going on here? Is `uname -m` misreporting the OS?

**Update** I know permissions aren't the problem. I ran `chown -R myusername mongodb/` and `chmod -R 777 mongodb/` with `mongodb/` being where I moved the untarred directory to.

Comment: What does `uname -a` say?

Comment: `uname -a` returns:
`Linux mormonmoves 3.9.3-x86_64-linode33 #1 SMP Mon May 20 10:22:57 EDT 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing shared libraries. Run `ldd ./bin/mongo` to see which ones.

However, you should use the 10gen repo. Do you see any configs in `/etc/apt/conf.d` setting `APT::Architecture`? If not, try forcing the architecture with `apt-get install mongodb-10gen:amd64`.

Edit: Are you using the 10gen repo? If not run `apt-add-repository http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/debian-sysvinit dist 10gen`

Edit2: WFM:

```
~/tmp$ curl http://downloads.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.4.tgz > mongodb.tgz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 90.2M  100 90.2M    0     0  4088k      0  0:00:22  0:00:22 --:--:-- 4393k
~/tmp$ tar -zxf mongodb.tgz
~/tmp$ cd mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.4/
~/tmp/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.4$ bin/mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.4
connecting to: test
Fri Jun 14 13:44:59.379 JavaScript execution failed: Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: `ldd ./bin/mongo` returned the same error, `ldd: ./bin/mongo: No such file or directory`

Running `apt-get install mongodb-10gen:amd64` returned `E: Unable to locate package mongodb-10gen:amd64`

Comment: Hmm...what does `echo bin/*` return?

Comment: It returns just `bin/*`

Comment: Since `apt-add-repository` gave an error that the command was not found, I tried adding that repo to my `/etc/apt/sources.list` instead. Using apt-get or aptitude after that still led to the 32-bit package being installed